# how to add a column in a data.table with both filtering and shifting

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to populate a conditional shift into a new column in a data.table but the shifted values jump over the filter `i`. Let me explain with an example.

Consider a data.table `dt1`

```
set.seed(20)
library(data.table)
dt1<-data.table(c1=sample(1:100,size = 10),c2=sample(101:200,size = 10))
> dt1
    c1  c2
 1: 88 172
 2: 77 176
 3: 28 101
 4: 52 173
 5: 93 119
 6: 94 143
 7:  9 131
 8:  7 111
 9: 31 127
10: 34 175
```

I want to create a new column `c3` which has values of vector `c1` shifted up by 1 (lagging shift) when `c1>50` else the shift need not be there and the value of `c1` must be copied. It is important to note that the shift has to be just previous value in the vector *without* the filter on.

So I am looking at this output (desired output):

```
dt1
    c1  c2 c3
 1: 88 172 NA  #shift activated
 2: 77 176 88  #shift activated
 3: 28 101 28  #shift not activated
 4: 52 173 28  #shift activated & filter not activated
 5: 93 119 52
 6: 94 143 93
 7:  9 131  9
 8:  7 111  7
 9: 31 127 31
10: 34 175 34
```

I tried these two successive transformations to get to the desired dt,

```
dt1[c1>50,c3:=shift(c1,n = 1,type = "lag")]
```

and

```
dt1[c1<50,c3:=c1]
```

but the output is incorrect, as posted below with commentary in front of each row

```
  c1  c2 c3
 1: 88 172 NA # correct
 2: 77 176 88 # correct
 3: 28 101 28 # correct
 4: 52 173 77 # incorrect (should be one earlier value ie 28)
 5: 93 119 52 # and rest are all correct
 6: 94 143 93 
 7:  9 131  9
 8:  7 111  7
 9: 31 127 31
10: 34 175 34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `ifelse` (if `c1` is greater than 50 return shifted `c1`, else return `c1`):

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, c3 := ifelse(c1 > 50, c(NA, c1[-.N]), c1)]
 #   c1  c2 c3
 # 1: 88 172 NA
 # 2: 77 176 88
 # 3: 28 101 28
 # 4: 52 173 28
 # 5: 93 119 52
 # 6: 94 143 93
 # 7:  9 131  9
 # 8:  7 111  7
 # 9: 31 127 31
 # 10: 34 175 34
```

PS.: There might be a smarter way to do `c(NA, c1[-.N])`

Answer (score 1):

`c(NA, c1[-.N])` is a neat trick.

You can also use `lag` from `dplyr` package.

```
require(dplyr)
dt1[,c3:=ifelse(c1 > 50, lag(c1), lag(c1,0))]
```

Comment: Both the solutions above work. The dplyr solution with `lag` was something I knew but got confused with `shift` of data.table. Also, I have moved on from dplyr to data.table for all my solutions so thanks @baci for reminding me that we can still use dplyr while inside a data.table. The data.table solution of @PoGibas actually taught me the use of ifelse() and .N use together so I am going to mark it as the answer. Thanks both.

Comment: hey @PoGibas, the solution you provided did not work on my actual data and then I realized there was a slight difference in my logic as presented with the representative example when compared to my real data. If it is a small tweak needed in your current solution please let me know in comments here, or if you think it is a major change, I can raise a new question. 

The actual requirement is that the if `c1 > 50`, `c3` should be the same as its own value but lagging by one. This means while `c1>50` all consecutive values of c3 should be the same.

Comment: I could manage to git my results using a for loop. Not sure if there is a better way without the loop.

`for (i in 2:nrow(dt1)) if(dt1$c1[i]>50) dt1$c2[i] <- dt1$c2[i-1] else dt1$c2[i] <-dt1$c1[i]`